# React js material ui customize inputbase responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui, responsive

[image]

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/customizedinputbase-material-demo-forked-kz6vux?file=/demo.js)

As you can see from the image I would like to say that when it shrinks below a certain threshold (for example mobile devices), the elements that are inside instead of being all elements one after the other become one below the other.

And each element takes up all the space in length.

How can I do?

Comment: Have a look at their code?

Comment: Which code? Whose?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you were asking about the icons in the codesandbox window.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with MUI's [responsive App Bar documentation](https://codesandbox.io/s/philolegein-drag-logging-fsnj4g?file=/src/App.js:3275-3733). Then you can style the menu component to be full-width.